# How to improve creativity for programming JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have learned front end development programming languages.
But I don't know how to create my own code because of lack of creativity...
Can you suggest how to solve this problem?

Comment: which kind of creativity u want to have at first day

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "inspiration", how about trying your hand at some [problem solving](https://open.kattis.com/)?

Comment: Practice. Pick your own project you want to work on even if you're just reinventing what someone else has done. Work through it. Repeat and hopefully you'll start making some original work eventually

Comment: Just think of something weird and try to build it, then build something else onto. Creativity comes from a lot of places... it doesn't always have to be a completely new idea, it can be two different ideas that come together to make something new. And don't think about what you'll use it for, just do whatever and if it finds a purpose later, so be it :) Quora might be a better forum for this question.

Answer (score 1):

When I first started with development in front end I was just like you. But I can give you some advices that worked for me for the last 3 years.

1. Reading blog of famous developer is a really good way. You can find here https://blog.digitalocean.com/20-developers-to-follow-in-2014/
2. Reading other code and demo, https://codepen.io/ this is one of my favorites.
3. Learn how to solved problem by design pattern. This is my favorite way to improve my coding skill. https://scotch.io/bar-talk/4-javascript-design-patterns-you-should-know . You can google for more results.
4. Take some courses about frontend development on https://www.udemy.com/ . When you watch someone coding, you will learn the way they thinking, the way the solved problem, the way they code, ....

Hope you have a good start.